# Need to develop a hierarchical structure from flat file using two identifiers in Input XML

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I am trying to develop a hierarchical structure from a flat file thus i need to establish parent child relationship in the desired output. Could you please suggest a method in XSLT 2.0.

Please find below the input XML which contains LEVEL and IDENTIFY tags on the basis of which i was trying to build the parent child relationship.

All the IDENTIFY tags with 'IB' should be in a separate tag like LOCATION and all the IDENTIFY tags with 'ER' should be in a separate tag like ADDRESS in output.

Input XML:

```
<Path>
<item>
<LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
<RANK>340</RANK>
<TYPE>T</TYPE>
<DESC>Sheet</DESC>
<NAME>I</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>IB</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
<RANK/>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC> Handler</DESC>
<NAME>D</NAME>
<IDENTIFY></IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
<RANK>341</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>handler </DESC>
<NAME>I</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>IB</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK/>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>pdf</DESC>
<NAME>D</NAME>
<IDENTIFY></IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK>330</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
 <DESC>SERVO </DESC>
<NAME>L</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK>331</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>SENSOR</DESC>
<NAME>L</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
<RANK>342</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>xyz</DESC>
<NAME>I</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>IB</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK>335</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>FILTER</DESC>
<NAME>L</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
<RANK>343</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>safety </DESC>
<NAME>I</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>IB</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK/>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>doc</DESC>
<NAME>D</NAME>
<IDENTIFY></IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK>337</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>ROD </DESC>
<NAME>L</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK>338</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>CYL</DESC>
<NAME>L</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
<RANK>339</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>COMPRESSION </DESC>
<NAME>L</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
<item>
<LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
<RANK>345</RANK>
<TYPE>M</TYPE>
<DESC>Nylon</DESC>
<NAME>I</NAME>
<IDENTIFY>ER</IDENTIFY>
</item>
</Path>
```

Desired Output:

```
    <LOCATION>
        <LEVEL>1</LEVEL>
        <RANK>340</RANK>
        <TYPE>T</TYPE>
        <DESC>Sheet</DESC>
        <NAME>I</NAME>
    </LOCATION>
            <LOCATION>
            <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
            <RANK/>
            <TYPE>M</TYPE>
            <DESC> Handler</DESC>
            <NAME>D</NAME>
            </LOCATION>
            <LOCATION>
            <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
            <RANK>341</RANK>
            <TYPE>M</TYPE>
            <DESC> handler </DESC>
            <NAME>I</NAME>
            </LOCATION>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK/>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                    <DESC>pdf</DESC>
                    <NAME>D</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK>330</RANK>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                    <DESC>pqr</DESC>
                    <NAME>L</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK>331</RANK>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                     <DESC>SENSOR</DESC>
                    <NAME>L</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
            <LOCATION>
                <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                <RANK>342</RANK>
                <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                 <DESC>xyz</DESC>
                <NAME>I</NAME>
            </LOCATION>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK>335</RANK>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                    <DESC>TER</DESC>
                    <NAME>L</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
            <LOCATION>
                <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                <RANK>343</RANK>
                <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                <DESC>SAFE</DESC>
                <NAME>I</NAME>
            </LOCATION>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK/>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                    <DESC>doc</DESC>
                    <NAME>D</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK>337</RANK>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                     <DESC>RST/DESC>
                    <NAME>L</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK>338</RANK>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                      <DESC>CYL</DESC>
                    <NAME>L</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
                <ADDRESS>
                    <LEVEL>3</LEVEL>
                    <RANK>339</RANK>
                    <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                    <DESC>COMP</DESC>
                    <NAME>L</NAME>
                </ADDRESS>
            <LOCATION>
                <LEVEL>2</LEVEL>
                <RANK>345</RANK>
                <TYPE>M</TYPE>
                <DESC>Nyl</DESC>
                <NAME>I</NAME>
            </LOCATION>
```

Comment: What kind of "hierarchy" does the desired output have? It has some misleading indentation but otherwise is a flat sequence of  `LOCATION` and `ADDRESS` element, it seems

Comment: Why are some items mapped to location and some mapped to address?

Comment: All the IDENTIFY tags with 'IB' should be in a separate tag like LOCATION and all the IDENTIFY tags with 'ER' should be in a separate tag like ADDRESS in output.